# Classical EM wave energy proportional to frequency ( valid argument)?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

I remember coming up with this argument as an undergrad and it came back to me the other day. I was curious: is the argument a valid one?

The following is purely classical.
Consider a plane electromagnetic wave being observed in reference frame $\mathcal{O}$, with observed energy, momentum and frequency ($E,P$, and $\omega$ respectivly).

In another frame $\mathcal{O}'$, boosted parallel to the direction of wave propagation, we have the observed quantities $E',P'$, and $\omega'$.

The quantities in $\mathcal{O}$ are related to those in $\mathcal{O}'$ via standard Lorentz transformations :

$$\omega'=\omega\sqrt{\frac{1\mp\beta}{1\pm\beta}}$$

$$E'=\frac{\left(E\mp c\beta P\right)}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}=E\frac{\left(1\mp\beta\right)}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}=E\sqrt{\frac{1\mp\beta}{1\pm\beta}}$$

Then for any such two frames $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$, we have the relation:

$$\frac{E'}{E}=\frac{\omega'}{\omega}$$

But this means that for *any* frame we have that:

$$\frac{E}{\omega}=\frac{E'}{\omega'}=C$$

Where $C$ independent of reference frame, meaning that the energy of this wave may be written as a Lorentz-invariant $C$ multiplied by the observed frequency of the wave!

But what is $C$, as there are no known individual wave properties that are Lorentz invariant?

One could consider $n$ superpositions of the wave with energy $E=n\omega C$, but that's out of the scope of my question.

Just to iterate: All I'm trying to argue here is that an arbitrary waves' energy measured in an arbitrary frame is dependent upon the wave frequency. I don't make the much stronger claim this constant is the same for all waves.

however it is fun to muse. Does another wave have the same constant C?  Ultimately as one digs into this question it becomes a matter of distinguishability vs. indistinguishability of electromagnetic waves (which of course we now know the answer to). If every wave has a different $C$ they are fundamentally distinguishable and you run into Gibbs paradox like problems.

If the argument is valid, I thought it was at least interesting that all you need is the covariance of electromagnetism (and indistinguishability of em waves) to infer that something like Planck's constant exists.

Comment: That’s not an argument that photons exist, that’s a confirmation  that the number of photons is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Also, $E/\omega$ isn’t constant for all electromagnetic waves. It depends on a lot of things, like the amplitude of the wave or how long it is.

Comment: @knzhou  It's really only meant to say classically wave energy is proportional to frequency, nothing about photons. you wouldn't get that until you apply frequency dependence of energy into blackbody radiation

Comment: @knzhou of course you're right about that, but  I could easily say it's energy per wavelength. The amplitude *is not* Lorentz invariant, so really the argument is saying that there is a dependency upon freqency in the amplitude.

Comment: The Gibbs paradox, like many paradoxes, is not a real problem in classical physics, it does not need quantum theory to resolve. It is a surprising (to the beginner) property of information entropy. Waves can be already distinguished by their direction and frequency, so making $C$ common to all waves won't make all waves indistinguishable.

Comment: @JánLalinský   that's like making electrons distinguishable by direction and momentum, which is clearly invalid thermodynamically (even classically). Having a C unique to each wave would end up being a lot more of a leap than saying they're the same (or related by integer multiples. ) However that is all outside the scope of the question (just a musing addendum to it).

Comment: > *"making electrons distinguishable by direction and momentum, which is clearly invalid thermodynamically (even classically)"* I have no idea what you mean. Particles are distinguishable in classical theory by their position, or momentum. We just leave them undistinguished in some considerations, such as when calculating entropy. Only in quantum theory when talking about single many-electron system described by single $\psi$, or field system described by second quantization, electrons are indistinguishable.

Comment: This implies that in special-relativistic theory, energy transforms the same way as frequency, and thus for the given wave packet, their ratio $E/\omega$ is Lorentz invariant. But the ratio can be anything, even zero. This implies nothing about existence of universal ratio  - it may exist, it may not. In classical theory it does not, in quantum theory it does.

Comment: @JánLalinský   A zero ratio would be no wave at all. Once again, I never claimed this implies there is a universal ratio C (for the 4th time). on another note Gibbs mixing paradox does immediately imply proper thermodynamics requires indistinguishability even in a classical setup.

Comment: "Energy is proportional to frequency" is not a well defined statement, because you haven't specified what is kept constant. The usual quantum version of this statement implicitly holds the number of photons constant, but that's not a thing classically.

Comment: The Gibbs paradox itself does not imply anything about proper thermodynamics requiring indistinguishability, that is a widely spread misconception. Divisor like $N!$ in the Boltzmann formula is put in to get entropy function that has similar mathematical properties as the Clausius entropy has, in particular dependence on $N$ (Clausius entropy is an extensive quantity). No assumption of indistinguishability is ever needed in classical statistical physics of gas or other systems to recover results of known experiments with it.

Comment: The dividing factor is correct even in a classical world where all gas particles are distinguishable into two groups and no experiment that can use that distinction to separate them is known. If such experiment was discovered later, we would simply stop using the divisor in the definition, and none of this would mean particles changed from indistinguishable to distinguishable. Indistinguishability is a quantum theory concept and has much better argument for it there.

Comment: @JánLalinský very true

Comment: @Javier Of course you are right. I really was interested in taking this argument a step further and using cosmological boundary conditions such as a closed universe. then one can show the ratio of two different wave's  C's is necessarily a rational number, implying the most general C is the product of an integer and a constant that's the same for all waves. All in good fun though.

Answer (score 2):

All you're saying is that if a specific wave packet has a ratio of energy to frequency of $C$, that ratio is the same in every inertial frame. But that doesn't constrain $C$ to be the same for every wave packet.

One way to see that C cannot be a classical constant is to consider a radar transmitter. Push out a 1 µs pulse from a 1 W exciter. The pulse has an energy of 1 µJ. Now, put a 1 kW amplifier on the exciter, leaving frequency and duration constant. Now, the pulse has 1 mJ of energy, but nothing else has changed. The energy isn't determined by the frequency.

Comment: My question title contains the only claim I am trying to argue

Comment: It occurs to me that classically we can calculate the number of electrons oscillating in the transmitter compared with that for one and then  The C for different energy outputs at the same frequency should always be an integer multiple of that for one electron. Of course now we're really just redoing physics from over a century ago, but the notion is there that there is some smaller fundamental constant. I can't think of an experiment, though I'm sure there is one, that doesn't ultimately tie back to the unit charge in some way.

Comment: @R.Rankin While electric charge is quantized, as far as we can tell potential is not. Transmitter output power depends on the potential it applies to the antenna.

Comment: I gotcha, this question was really for fun in a "how far can you get without a quanta hypothesis sort of way" like the ancient Greeks and they're speculations on atoms